# The text inputs are functioning properly, but there seems to be an issue with the select inputs

Tags: ionic-framework, react-hook-form

The text inputs are functioning properly, but the select inputs seem to be an issue. I can't focus select html elements. I'm using Ionic with React + React hook form. This solution is working for text inputs but doesn't for select components.

I've tried with the solution in this post.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.